# Plotting Based on Column Headers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a feeling this may be a basic problem but I'm struggling to find an answer anywhere.....
I have a dataset which begins with a date columns and then a number of columns of data for each date

```
Date                `Day Name`  Player.Name Min_1 Min_2 Min_3 Min_4 Min_5 
Min_6 Min_7 Min_8 Min_9
<dttm>              <chr>       <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-04-05 00:00:00 Attack_3G   Adams Josh   142.  131.  120.  118. 117.  
114.  112.  110.  106. 
2 2018-04-03 00:00:00 Defence_3G  Adams Josh   141.  136.  119.  107. 114.  
110.  106.  103.  102. 
3 2018-04-07 00:00:00 Newcastle_H Adams Josh   164.  134.  125.  131. 123.  
122.  123.  118.  116. 
4 2018-04-09 00:00:00 Rugby_Games Adams Josh   143.  119.  106.  102.  99.1  
96.1  95.8  93.3  93.1
5 2018-04-10 00:00:00 Defence_3G  Adams Josh   151.  125.  118.  115. 105.  
105.  104.   98.3  99.2
```

I'm looking to produce something simliar to this grapg (made in excel) using ggplot but I'm struggling to produce it
[image: e]

I have been slightly inspired by this https://github.com/dylanjm/tidy_tuesday/blob/master/tidy_02/tidy_02.pdf
but I know I'm a long way doing that

Edit:

```
dput(DataAdams)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1522886400, 1522713600, 1523059200, 
1523232000, 1523318400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
`Day Name` = c("Attack_3G", "Defence_3G", "Newcastle_H", 
"Rugby_Games", "Defence_3G"), Player.Name = c("Adams Josh", 
"Adams Josh", "Adams Josh", "Adams Josh", "Adams Josh"), 
Min_1 = c(142.1, 141, 164.4085833, 143.210266666667, 151.231866666667
), Min_2 = c(130.6, 136, 134.1398417, 118.640983333333, 124.572875
), Min_3 = c(120.3, 119, 125.4481778, 105.878772222222, 117.834138888889
), Min_4 = c(118, 107, 130.7162417, 102.362020833333, 115.113870833333
), Min_5 = c(116.7, 114, 123.2527933, 99.13397, 105.461176666667
), Min_6 = c(114.5, 109.91, 122.4857556, 96.0797777777778, 
104.625694444444), Min_7 = c(112.5, 106.33, 122.9992643, 
95.7929095238095, 103.714069047619), Min_8 = c(109.6, 103.25, 
117.8601313, 93.2561125, 98.3237854166667), Min_9 = c(105.8, 
101.79, 115.9276407, 93.0925740740741, 99.2409627156372)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Day Name", "Player.Name", "Min_1", "Min_2", "Min_3", "Min_4", 
"Min_5", "Min_6", "Min_7", "Min_8", "Min_9"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. How is the data that goes into each line divided up?

Comment: your data is missing groups such as `attack_3G, defence_3G and so on`

Comment: use `dput(data)` and copy paste its output to your question. It will give us a reproducible example

Comment: make the data long and use `ggplot2`

Comment: Sorry had, removed the `attack_3G` etc by mistake. Added `dput` output also. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset would not produce the example plot. There are two "Defence_3G" rows. So to simplify I'll ignore the last row.

```
library(tidyverse)
adams <- DataAdams %>% slice(1:4)
```

So the first issue is that your data is untidy in a way often seen with Excel spreadsheets. The "variables" Min_1 etc. are actually data values. Anyway, we need to put the data into "long" format, as follows. `gather` is from `tidyr` which is loaded as part of core `tidyverse`.

```
adams_long <- adams %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Player.Name, -Date, -`Day Name`)
```

Have a look at this data frame to see what it looks like. Now it's ready for `ggplot`.

```
adams_long %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value, colour = `Day Name`)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(group=`Day Name`))
```

[image]

And there are lots of ways to tweak the look and feel.

Comment: Thanks this works, this is part of a larger dataset, just working my through it step by step when it comes to plotting the data